# Why is this hand the nuts?

Tags: texas-hold-em, no-limit, hand, nuts

In the book *No Limit Hold 'em: Theory and Practice*, at page 62, the author gives an example of a bad bluff during the 1979 World Series of Poker Main event.  The cards on the table after the river are A:spades: K:spades: Q:clubs: T:clubs: 7:spades:.  The author then says that any jack makes the nuts, but isn't the nuts a flush with a pair of spades in hand, thus beating the straight from the jack?  I'm adding the relevant parts from the book.  Thanks for the help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first flop card is ace of hearts,not spades.

Comment: Woops, I feel dumb now, I guess the black and white confused me.  Thanks!